# Select n rows without LIMIT mysql

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a problem. I would like to get only 300 rows from table without touching LIMIT. I need LIMIT for pagination. Is this possible in MySQL?

My current query:

```
SELECT a.title, a.askprice, a.picture, a.description, a.userid, a.id 
    FROM mm_ads AS a WHERE a.category = 227 AND a.status = 1 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40,20
```

**Edit:**

Simple explanation: I need to get from a system last 300 ads but I need to keep pagination, because I don't want to have 300 rows listed in one page..

Comment: Why would you want to collect more records than you'll fit on the page? If you need to show records 20 to 40 you don't need the other 280 records to get collected....

Comment: I guess you'll have to provide more information instead of implying an unusable solution without telling what it's for.

Comment: You can use LIMIT both for pagination and limiting the overall result set simply by not querying pages which are above the limit or trimming result length if limit doesn't fit to pagination boundary. *Don't* write a complicated query to separate the two (or give a terribly good reason to do so).

Comment: Which 300 rows are you interested in? The first 300 always?

Comment: @hakre: Yes, I need first 300 rows..

Comment: @Puzo: What is your problem then? The SQL query in your question already returns the records 40-59 from the first 300.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT a.title, a.askprice, a.picture, a.description, a.userid, a.id 
   FROM mm_ads AS a 
   WHERE a.category = 227 AND a.status = 1 
   ORDER BY id DESC 
   LIMIT 300
) t
LIMIT 40,20
```

If the purpose is to speed up the query, then you can create a composite index:

```
ALTER TABLE `mm_ads` 
    ADD INDEX `mm_ads_index` (`category` ASC, `status` ASC, `id` DESC);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that...?

Comment: @hoppa I don't know. It is just a direct answer to his question :)

Comment: Semantically it is a correct answer yes, but it overcomplicates the query by a great deal which is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Karolis Thank you for your quick reply and direct answer but this query is too slow.. I have 50 000+ rows so I need to focus on speed performance..

Comment: @Puzo So you wanted to limit the result set to 300 rows because you wanted to speed up the query? This was the purpose?

Comment: Is the user only allowed to see the 300 latest ads?

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS after your SELECT:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
```

EDIT:

And in php, run this row to get the amount of rows:

```
list($int_rows) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"));
```

This will go through all the rows, get the total amount, but not fetch all the rows.

EDIT2:

May have misunderstod your question, however this is a common solution for pagination.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.. But I don't think, that this is what I am looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is
Fits count only amount of result you need and use it in your pagination
then use limit in your query to load data on each page

SELECT a.title, a.askprice, a.picture, a.description, a.userid, a.id 
    FROM mm_ads AS a WHERE a.category = 227 AND a.status = 1 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40,20

it dosen't matter how large your data base is it only gives you the 20 results (although it search for full database)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that you can do is just fetch all the 300 rows from database and save it in an array and then paginate the array indexes